# Service Fabric Application deployment

Tags: c#, azure, azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-stateful, service-fabric-stateless

Registering service fabric application fails with error

*"The application package 'ServiceFabricApp' is not found in the store. Make sure that the package was previously copied to the store. If the package was previously provisioned successfully, the temporary package may have been removed based on the cleanup policies."*

More context, I am using service fabric APIs to connect, create/upgrade application. 
Following this doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-deploy-remove-applications-fabricclient#code-example

Able to copy the application package to the local path some "C:\ImageFolder" (able to verify that the package exists and there is Read-only permission on that folder). I am running into issues on ***ProvisionApplicationAsync***.

```
    try
    {
        fabricClient.ApplicationManager.ProvisionApplicationAsync(packagePathInImageStore).Wait();

        Console.WriteLine("Provisioned application type {0}", packagePathInImageStore);
    }
    catch (AggregateException ae)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Provision Application Type failed:");

        foreach (Exception ex in ae.InnerExceptions)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("HResult: {0} Message: {1}", ex.HResult, ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

with error:

*The application package 'ServiceFabricApp' is not found in the store. Make sure that the package was previously copied to the store. If the package was previously provisioned successfully, the temporary package may have been removed based on the cleanup policies.*

CopyApplication code:

```
   string imageStoreConnectionString = "file:C:\ImageFolder";
   string packagePathInImageStore = "ServiceFabricApp";
   try
    {
        fabricClient.ApplicationManager.CopyApplicationPackage(imageStoreConnectionString, packagePath, packagePathInImageStore);
        Console.WriteLine("Application package copied to {0}", packagePathInImageStore);
    }
    catch (AggregateException ae)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Application package copy to Image Store failed: ");
        foreach (Exception ex in ae.InnerExceptions)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("HResult: {0} Message: {1}", ex.HResult, ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Had to change the Image store to : fabric:ImageStore

More details here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-image-store-connection-string